# MySQL - Get multiple values for the same column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a friend system for my website and it is set up something like this:

```
User's Table:
id
name

Friendship Table:
member1
member2
```

So what I want is that when I have values like this (member1 is the user's id and member2 is the friend's id:

```
member1 - member2
1           2
1           3
1           5
```

I want to be able to get all of the user's (id of 1 in example) friend's ids. But when I use mysql_fetch_assoc in PHP I get only one of the member2 ids. So even though the member1 has the ids 2,3 and 5 in his friend list, I can only get one of his friend's ids. Is there any way to fix this so that I can get all of his friend's ids?
Thanks

Comment: so, what output do you get? I'm not sure what you mean by 'But when I use mysql_fetch_assoc in PHP I get only one of the member2 ids'. Do you only get one at a time, or one in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you want get friendship table. The table has column: member1 and member2. To get member2 value based on member1,

```
<?php
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_table");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1))
{
    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friendship_table WHERE member1='".$r1['id']."'");
    while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2))
    {
        echo $r2['member2'];
    }
}
?>
```

Or use sql join statement.

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM user_table JOIN friendship_table WHERE user_table.id=friendship_table.member1");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    echo $r['member2'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I am using that but I still get only one friend id rather than all the friend ids.

Comment: what is your sql query. For that while loop, I will use: "SELECT member1,member2 FROM friendship_table WHERE member1=1",  then use while loop for fetch value.

Comment: I  update my answer, First looping to get member1 ID and second loop, to get member2. Other way, you can use SQL JOIN statement.

Answer (score 1):

As any decent PHP database tutorial would show, call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in a loop until it returns `false`.

Comment: I am using while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){...} to do it but I still only get one friend id. Any ideas?

Comment: You will only get one at a time. If you need to process more than one at a time then you will need to store them and then process after.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I'm kind of a beginner. Can you please show me what you mean? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If processing on the webserver is less of a bottleneck than bandwidth to the MySQL server, use

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(member2) FROM Friendship where member1=...
```

and then

```
$ids=explode(',',$resultfield)
```

in PHP